# FileStream not reading FileName input from external class

Tags: c#, .net, file, hex

I'm trying to make a byte writer. So far I have made the program write the file header as a general test before I continue coding the writer. The problem is, after I select a file through `coreForm`'s `coreSaveFileDialog`, the line

```
var fs = new FileStream(classCoreForm.CoreSaveFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
```

doesn't see the FileName from the dialog, and throws an exception saying "Empty path name is not legal."

Here's the source of my method:

```
internal void writeHeader()
    {
        var classCoreForm = new coreForm(); //Creates reference instance for coreForm=
        var fs = new FileStream(classCoreForm.coreSaveFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        /*
         * Writes file header via fs.WriteByte . . .
         */
    }
```

`writeHeader` is being called from a preliminary function called `saveScript`. Here's its source.

```
internal void saveScript()
    {
        var classCoreForm = new coreForm(); //Creates reference instance for coreForm
        if (fileAlreadySaved == false)
        {
            classCoreForm.coreSaveFileDialog.ShowDialog(); //Shows save file dialog
            if (classCoreForm.coreSaveFileDialog.FileName != "")
            {
                writeHeader();
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? Have I incorrectly set something in the SaveFileDialog's properties, or is it something within the code above?

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint on the line with `new FileStream(...)` to see what the `Filename` property returns?

Comment: It's a stopping point for the debugger. You toggle one in Visual Studio by pressing F9 on the line where you want to pause execution during debugging. You start debugging by pressing F5. When execution reaches the breakpoint, the code will pause on that line and you can inspect the program state. You can then run forward (F5) or step over / into function calls (F10 / F11 but I'm unsure, I have a custom setup).

Comment: wait, I saw in the locals window that the `FileName` property is null. Hold on, let me edit my post.

Comment: What's the return value of the `ShowDialog()` function? If it's not `DialogResult.Ok`, you won't have a filename returned to you. Also, what file are you trying to open? Certain folders in Windows Explorer are really virtual folders and may not return a filename in the file system. In that case you may get null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

saveScript() calls writeHeader, but it doesn't pass anything in to writeHeader. You're then creating a completely new instance of "coreForm" which is separate from the instance you created in the saveScript method.

Change writeHeader to accept a file name as an argument:

```
internal void writeHeader(string fileName)
{
    //var classCoreForm = new coreForm(); //Creates reference instance for coreForm=
    var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    /*
     * Writes file header via fs.WriteByte . . .
     */
}
```

Then, in your saveScript() method, change writeHeader(); to

```
writeHeader(classCoreForm.coreSaveFileDialog.FileName);
```

If you need the coreForm for other reasons in saveScript, you may want to pass the coreForm by reference, or pass in the other variables you might need into saveScript.